# error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Tags: git

I would like to run this Git command:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/example/example.git
```

But I get this error:

> Cloning into 'C:/projects/xxx/yyy/zzz/'... 
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
>   CApath: none
>   fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git' into submodule path 'C:/projects/xxx/yyy/zzz/example' failed

So, to fix this, I am trying to run this command:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

But I get this error message:

> error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

How can I fix this?

Comment: You must likely run the command as an administrator, alternatively just skip the `--system` toggle.

Comment: I've got a similar problem (clone attempt gives: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
) ... if you change --system to --global it sets some git config in your home folder rather than C:/Program Files... - still hasn't solved my problem

Answer (score 22):

you need to be in admin mode to execute the command (in cmd terminal or in PowerShell (Admin) on windows10)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with `Git Bash` reporting the fatal "error setting certificate verify locations" for the `git pull` command. The actual problem turned out to be authentication, as I had recently changed my Windows password. The solution was to remove the git credentials in Credential Manager (Windows 7 | Control Panel | All Control Panel Items | Credential Manager), then try `git pull` twice to force `Git Bash` to supply the Windows popup prompting for the new password. No more certificate errors.

In the past after changing Windows password, we have only had to log out of BitBucket in order for Git Bash to initiate the Windows popup for entering the new password. This time the popup did not appear, and I started receiving the certificate error, so removing the credentials was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, gitconfig was on another disk "D:\Program Files\Git\etc"

Edited the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\gitconfig"

Changed the parameter

```
path = D:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig
```