# error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/.gitconfig: Permission denied

Tags: git, windows-7

**Getting below error while trying to config username and user email:**

*error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/.gitconfig: Permission denied*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140830/error-could-not-lock-config-file-c-program-files-git-mingw64-etc-gitconfig-pe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+could+not+lock+config+file+.gitconfig%3A+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

This error can be due to several things. If you have a file `.gitconfig.lock`, you cannot lock the config file. Just delete `.gitconfig.lock` and everything should be fine.

Another possibility is that you have no write permissions to that file. You can check if you own the file with (assuming `.gitconfig` is located at `~/`):

```
ls -la ~/.gitconfig
```

The second column shows the owner. If the file doesn't belong to you (i.e. your user), you can change ownership (assuming `.gitconfig` is located at `~/`):

```
# note: omit the <>
sudo chown <your_username>:<your_username> ~/.gitconfig
```

If the file belongs to you, and you still cannot write to it, you might want to set write permissions (assuming `.gitconfig` is located at `~/`):

```
sudo chmod 755 ~/.gitconfig
```